# Adding rule to indentation

Tags: indentation, c

A code base I work on has the macro

`#define when break; case`

to make switch statements 'cleaner'

However this causes problems with indentation,

Is it possible to set the behavior of 'when' to be the same as 'case'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promoted way would be to add a new `cc-mode` with `c-add-language` (see [the example](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/derived-mode-ex.el) ) linked in [`cc-langs.el`](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/src/cc-langs.el). But that is a bit heavy for the task at hand.

It is simpler to add `when` as a font lock keyword and as a matcher in `c-labels-kwds-regexp`.
You can use the following `c-mode-hook`:

```el
(defun my-c-setup ()
  "Run in `c-mode-hook'."
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("when" . 'font-lock-keyword-face)))
  (setq c-label-kwds-regexp (replace-regexp-in-string "case" "case\\\\|when" c-label-kwds-regexp)))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'my-c-setup)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, after I removed the '#' from the add-hook part. I haven't done much elisp. Is that a typo or something that I'm missing the point of?

Comment: @Mitchk The sharp quote `#'` stands for wrapping the quoted form with `(function ...)`. You should use it everywhere you could syntactically replace the function symbol (here `my-c-setup`) with a lambda. See the item about sharp quotes in [Section "Functions" of the Elisp style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide#functions) and also the [corresponding discussion](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide/issues/7). There is also a [nice article from Malabarba](https://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html) about that.